# How can flutter test frame work be used to test Clipboard?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, flutter-test, dart-test

How can I test code that uses `Clipboard` in Dart.  It will not work from the test framework.

The code works well when run from a main programme (after `runApp(..)`).  But the following test fails

This is the code I want to test:

```
  Future setText(String input) async {
    ClipboardData data = ClipboardData(text: input);
    await Clipboard.setData(data);
    if (!await Clipboard.hasStrings()) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Added string, no strings!");  // 
      }
    }
  }
Future<String?> getText() async {
    if (await Clipboard.hasStrings()) {
      ClipboardData? result = await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);
      if (result == null) {
        return null;
      }
      return result.text;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

I have test code...

```
void main() async {
  test("Test copying data to and from the clipboard", () async {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    String testStringPut = "ABC def 123 ";
    await setText(testStringPut);
    String? testStringGet = await getText();
    expect(testStringGet, testStringPut);
 });
}
```

The line: `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` is some sort of magic incantation as far as I know, and is probably where my problem lies.

Without it I get the error:

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Binding has not yet been initialized.
The "instance" getter on the ServicesBinding binding mixin is only available once that binding has been initialized.
Typically, this is done by calling "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" or "runApp()" (the latter calls the former). Typically this call is done in the "void main()" method. The "ensureInitialized" method is idempotent; calling it multiple times is not harmful. After calling that method, the "instance" getter will return the binding.
In a test, one can call "TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" as the first line in the test's "main()" method to initialize the binding.
If ServicesBinding is a custom binding mixin, there must also be a custom binding class, like WidgetsFlutterBinding, but that mixes in the selected binding, and that is the class that must be constructed before using the "instance" getter.)
```